# Modeling mean-reversion for different volatility regimes

Tags: volatility, mean-reversion, ornstein-uhlenbeck

**Motivation**: Half-life (HL) period shows how long it takes for a mean-reverting process to return halfway to its mean after a deviation. Most commonly, an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck (OU) process is applied to estimate HL period. However, financial data embeds volatility clustering, i.e., high/low volatility regimes cluster together, and, by construction, the HL estimated in an OU framework does not capture in which volatility regime is our process. Intuitively, mean reversion should be faster in a high volatility regime, and therefore HL shorter, than in a low volatility regime.

**Question(s):**  (**a**) How it is possible to model OU process by capturing volatility clustering feature of the time series and distinguish between high and low volatility regimes? (**b**) How estimate HL period for different states of volatility regime, i.e. allowing HL to be different for high and low volatility regimes. (This could be done in a different framework than an OU, if necessary).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was trying to incorporate (G)ARCH errors in the model, but not sure how to define HL as a function of time-varying volatility.